# Detect UITextField Lost Focus

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitextfield, protocols

i searched a lot googling and heree, but nothing useful.

I have two textfields and i don't able to recognize which one lost the focus.
I tried all options, but nothing.

Here the `textFieldDidEndEditing`:

```
- (void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {  
  NSLog(@"%@", [textField state]);
  NSLog(@"%d", [textField isSelected]);
  NSLog(@"%d", [textField isFirstResponder]);
  NSLog(@"%d", [textField isHighlighted]);
  NSLog(@"%d", [textField isTouchInside]);

  if ( ![textField isFirstResponder] || ![textField isSelected] ) {
  //if ( [textField state] != UIControlStateSelected) {
    NSLog(@"not selected!");
    [...]
    // remove view / etc...
  }
}
```

All NSLog returns 0! Why?!?

How can i detect lost focus? This method has called every time that i press a keyboard button, non only at the end!
Is there any alternatives?

**EDIT**:
I don't want to switch from texts but i want to detect lost focus when i click anyways on screen. (the keyboard will dismiss or not and the caret is not present on textfield)!

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To handle tapping outside text fields you can override `touchesBegan` in your view controller:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if ([textField1 isFirstResponder] && (textField1 != touch.view))
    {
        // textField1 lost focus
    }

    if ([textField2 isFirstResponder] && (textField2 != touch.view))
    {
        // textField2 lost focus
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: You can handle it in `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` by checking the first responder:

Comment: this isn't very reliable.. `touchesBegan` isn't called every time i touch somethign on the screen for some reason

Answer (score 2):

```
 - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
      NSLog(@"%d",textFiled.tag);
      NSInteger nextTag = textField.tag + 1;
      UIResponder* nextResponder = [textField.superview viewWithTag:nextTag];   
      if (nextResponder) {
          [nextResponder becomeFirstResponder];
      } else {          
          [textField resignFirstResponder];
      }
      return YES;
  }
```

The UITextField with tag had lost focus in textFieldShouldReturn method

This will help you to go from one TextField to another....just set tag incremently in all TextFields ex : 0,1,2,3....etc

Comment: No, no, it's not correct!! In this way, I don't able to get lost focus when i click outside the textfield without use ShouldReturn!!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer since you asked about how to handle when losing focus. I think there are times when it's nice to have explicit save and cancel buttons to dismiss. Especially on a text view where you want to preserve the return key for it's intended use.

This is a class which adds a toolbar to the keyboard with "Done" and "Cancel" buttons. I have this working in iOS 8 right now. I am pretty new to iOS so there might be better ways to do this. Always open to suggestions on how to improve.

DismissableTextView.h...

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DismissableTextView : UITextView

@end
```

DismissableTextView.m...

```
#import "DismissableTextView.h"

@implementation DismissableTextView

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setInputView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        [self setInputView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self setInputView];
}

- (void) setInputView {
    [self createToolbar];
}
-(void) createToolbar {

    // Create toolbar for the keyboard so it can be dismissed...
    UIToolbar* toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
    toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
    toolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(cancelClicked)],
                           [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                           [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Apply" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(doneClicked)],
                           nil];
    [toolbar sizeToFit];

    self.inputAccessoryView = toolbar;
}

- (IBAction)didBeginEditDescription:(id)sender
{
}

-(void)cancelClicked{

    // respond to cancel click in the toolbar
    [self resignFirstResponder];
}

-(void)doneClicked{

    // respond to done click in the toolbar
    [self resignFirstResponder];
}

@end
```

Answer (score -3):

When you are creating the text fields, assign different tags to them:

```
#define kSomeTag 100
textField.tag = kSomeTag;
```

In your - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField method, you can tell which textfield ended editing by querying its tag:

```
if (textField.tag == kSomeTag) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: No, not work because when i click outside textfield nothing change! Tag is the same, it's indifferent!!!