# UITableView onTouch hide keypad

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a `UITableView` wherein I have placed a `UIButton` (as a subview of cell). Also below the table, I have a `UITextField`. On touching the textField, the keypad appears as usual. What I want is to dismiss the keypad on touching the table.

One option which I considered was setting `UITapGestureRecognizer` for `UITableView`. But I threw up that idea as I have a button on tableCell which then becomes unresponsive.

Also, I don't want Done or return button on keypad. What I mean to say is, I don't want the keypad to disappear from keypad but on touching the table taking care of the button it has.

Comment: check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6370673/641062

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be you can try this.

```
//NSnotification when keyboard is shown
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification  *)notification
{    
    //  Get the size of the keyboard.
    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){

        if(UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait==orientation || UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown==orientation){
            keyboardSize=CGSizeMake(320.000000, 216.000000);
        }
     else if(UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft==orientation || UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight==orientation)
        {
            keyboardSize=CGSizeMake(162.000000, 480.000000);
        }
    }
    else if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
        if(UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait==orientation || UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown==orientation)
            keyboardSize=CGSizeMake(768.000000, 264.000000);        

        else if(UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft==orientation || UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight==orientation)
        {
            keyboardSize=CGSizeMake(352.000000,1024.000000);

        }
    }

    //  Adjust the bottom content inset of your scroll view by the keyboard height.
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize.height, 0.0);
    scrvwLogig.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrvwLogig.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    // Scroll the target text field into view.
    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize.height;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, txtpassword.frame.origin) ) {

        CGPoint scrollPoint=CGPointZero;
        //check flag for iPhone orientation
        if(flgLandScape)        
           scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, txtpassword.frame.origin.y-70);
        //check flag for iPhone/iPad orientation
        else if(flgPort || flgPortiPad)
           scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, txtpassword.frame.origin.y - (keyboardSize.height-50));        
        //check flag for ipad orientation
         else if(flgLandScapeiPad)        
          scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, txtpassword.frame.origin.y-130);  

        [scrvwLogig setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
    }
}


//when keyboard is hide

- (void) keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification {

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    scrvwLogig.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrvwLogig.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `UIView` (OR UIButton). Before keyboard appears, add a transparent `UIView` (320x480) and on touch event of that view, you can hide keyboard and remove the view.

Comment: @Nitish: hmm true... so you want to hide keyboard when scroll or touch ?

Comment: @Nitish: Another way you can try is when table scrolls hide keyboard.

Comment: I want to hide keypad on touch. But the table can scroll.